# Django: select template from data in settings

Tags: django

I am trying to understand the process whereby a Django template might be selected based on data in the settings file. So, as an example if I have:

`SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = "my_fb_key"`

I would like the template selection in `urls.py` to do this:

`url('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='choose_signup.html'), name='login')`

But if the FB key value is empty/null I’d like it to do this:

`url('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='really_login.html'), name='login')`

I tried setting a variable in urls.py like this:

```
if SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY == "" :
    mytemplatename = "really_login.html"
else:
    mytemplatename = "choose_signup.html"

…

url('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name=mytemplatename), name='login')
```

But this produces an error in terminal (`manage.py runserver`)

`NameError: name 'SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY' is not defined`

Am I just trying to do this the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY` is not defined. You need to import the settings:

```
from django.conf import settings

...


if settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY == "" :
    ...
```

From the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/#using-settings-in-python-code

Comment: Thank you. I'd already imported `settings`, and there was another reference in the `urls.py` file (`settings.MEDIA_URL`), I'm obviously not concentrating!